# Rewrite Java method draw() in QT

Tags: java, qt, porting

I have the method `draw(Graphics g)`

```
public void draw(Graphics g){
    switch(id){
        default:
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid id in contructor");
            break;
        case 1:
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
            break;
        case 2:
            g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
            break;
    }
}
```

How to rewrite it for QT? Or what method should I use instead(like the method `keyReleased(KeyEvent e)` in Java  is `keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *e)` in QT)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on what you are drawing.

if your are drawing a `QWidget`, it will probably be a `QWidget::paintEvent()`

if you are drawing a `QGraphicsItem`, it should be a `QGraphicsItem::paint()`

also, those methods take different kind of arguments. It could be a `QPaintEvent` or a `QPainter` respectively. Please refer to corresponding documentation

Comment: Do I need to inherit QWidget for my class? or inheritance in QMainWindow is enough?

Comment: i don't know about _inheritance in QMainWindow_ but if it's for a QWidget-like class then yes you should use `paintEvent`. I see you are drawing shapes with `fillRect`; if the class is supposed to display graphics stuff, I suggest you take a look at the powerful [Qt Graphics View Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html)

Comment: Yes, I draw several rectangles and a ball(pong game)

Comment: ok then. take a look at [one implementation](http://code.google.com/p/gtxpong/source/browse/trunk/Racquet.h) of pong game using Qt Graphics View framework